# C# SQL AND condition not working on string data

Tags: c#, sql

I was hoping someone could help me out with this stupid problem I'm having with the following SQL statement:

```
public void ApplyInference(string AnswerSelected)
    {
        int InferenceID;
        int QuestionID;
        string AnswerInference;
        int PainValue;
        int AnxietyValue;
        int DepressionValue;
        int FearValue;
        int TransportValue;
        int EmotionalValue;
        int FinancialValue;
        int PhysicalValue;
        int SpiritValue;
        int SocialValue;            

        SqlConnection NewConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\QuestionsDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"); //"Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        SqlDataReader ReadIn = null;

        try
        {
            NewConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand GetInference = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM InferenceDB WHERE QuestionID =" + this.QuestionID + "AND AnswerInference =" + AnswerSelected, NewConnection);
            ReadIn = GetInference.ExecuteReader();

            while (ReadIn.Read())
            {
                InferenceID = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[0]);
                QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[1]);
                AnswerInference = Convert.ToString(ReadIn[2]);
                PainValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[3]);
                AnxietyValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[4]);
                DepressionValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[5]);
                FearValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[6]);
                TransportValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[7]);
                EmotionalValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[8]);
                FinancialValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[9]);
                PhysicalValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[10]);
                SpiritValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[11]);
                SocialValue = Convert.ToInt32(ReadIn[12]);



                MessageBox.Show("InferenceID: " + InferenceID + "\nAnswer Value: " + AnswerInference + "\nPain value: " + PainValue + "\nSocial value: " + SocialValue);
                //LoadQuestionForm(this.FormStyle);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ReadIn != null)
            {
                ReadIn.Close();
            }

            if (NewConnection != null)
            {
                NewConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }`
```

Now the code works tor every other column in the table except for the one I need which is the AnswerInference one. I am feeding the AnswerInference value in from another method which looks like this:

```
private void Answer1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            parent.ApplyInference("Ans1");
            CloseForm();
        }
```

Unfortunately I can't get the code to work using string data found in the table I'm using. I know this should be an easy fix, but I can for the life of me work out what's going on. Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After you fix your issue, you should really learn about prepared SQL statements.

Comment: LOOK INTO PARAMETERS... seriously, that is just ripe for a SQL injection attack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between the question-id and the and, but more importantly: you should use parameters. Look into "SQL injection", query-plan re-use, etc. The most appropriate way to do this is with a command like:

```
using(var GetInference = new SqlCommand(@"
SELECT *
FROM InferenceDB
WHERE QuestionID = @questionID AND AnswerInference = @answerInference"
       , NewConnection);
{
    GetInference.Parameters.AddWithValue("questionID", QuestionID);
    GetInference.Parameters.AddWithValue("answerInference", AnswerSelected);
    ....
}
```

Also - that complex-looking `try`/`finally` can be simplified with `using` here.

Comment: But AnswerInference is a string variable passed by another method, so the query must accept an "unknown" variable and not perform a standard query. The problem seems to lie with the variable being passed in from the calling method, and I keep getting error: "Invalid column name 'Ans1'....

Comment: @Adam which is exactly **why** it needs to be parameterised! The query I show above ***will not*** behave as you describe, precisely *because* it is parameterised correctly. Please, try it.

Comment: @Adam more generally, if you are routinely concatenating values to create TSQL strings... *stop doing that*. It is really, really, honestly, madly, deeply, truly: dangerous. Plus it makes your server work harder (it can't re-use plans).

Comment: I've just started to use SQL and C# so I'm just learning the ropes. I will keep that in mind for future reference for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

You need a space before the `AND`

```
"SELECT *
FROM InferenceDB
WHERE QuestionID = " + this.QuestionID + " AND AnswerInference = " + AnswerSelected
```